# tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths Animation not working

Tags: objective-c, animation, parse-platform, tableview, delete-row

This is something strange that I can't seem to figure out.
I'm using Parse back end and displaying a TableView to load data and swiping to delete it.

The code works except for one part: 
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

If I leave that code in the app crashes if I comment it out it works fine but without the animation. I checked putting in NSLog statements to print out indexPath.row to make sure I'm removing and that I have the correct number of total rows. But why would it work perfectly fine without the animation but crash w/ the animation?

The error message I received is:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

My code is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self retrieveOrders];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@'s Orders", currentUser.username);
    }

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]; // Refresher MBProgress Hud
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveOrders) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; // Refresher MBProgress Hud
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.ordersArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    PFObject *order = [self.ordersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogPost.thumbnailURL];
//    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
//    cell.imageView.image = image;

    _updatedAt = order.updatedAt;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"treehouse.png"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", order[@"recepientName"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shipped on %@", self.formatDate];
    return cell;
}

- (void)retrieveOrders {
    PFQuery *orderQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Orders"];
    [orderQuery orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];

    [orderQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.ordersArray = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        }
    }];
}

-(NSString *) formatDate{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_updatedAt];
    NSString *newTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]init]];
    return newTime;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    PFObject *removeObject = [self.ordersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *deleteId = removeObject.objectId;
    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Orders" objectId:deleteId];
    [object deleteInBackground];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Animate the deletion from the table.
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call `retrieveOrders` after calling `deleteInBackground`, so that `self.ordersArray` is probably still holding a reference to your "deleted" object. `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is expecting the number of rows to be different.

Also, `deleteInBackground` is run in the background and so calling `retrieveOrders` may not even completely solve your problem.

**EDIT**

You can also try this...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        PFObject *removeObject = [self.ordersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *deleteId = removeObject.objectId;
        PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Orders" objectId:deleteId];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried calling retrieveOrders after the deletion and no luck :(

Comment: OK, you should read Parse's docs to see if the Parse object waits for a response from the server about successful deletions before local Parse installations are updated to reflect the deletion.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. I added [self.ordersArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; before calling the animation... BUT my ordersArray is originally a NSArray and I had to change it to a NSMutableArray. The only thing is the code works but is giving me a yellow warning in my retrieveOrders method in the line "self.ordersArray = objects;"

Comment: The warning is probably telling you that you are assigning a NSArray to an object whose type is NSMutableArray. See my other solution.